# Soft Keyboard Arrow Keys

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I am creating a custom keyboard for android devices and i have managed to implement everything but being able to move up and down lines through the use of buttons not just dragging with your finger. I am implementing this for small screens of older devices.

I have managed to implement moving the cursor one character to the left and right and to the end and start of the text how ever i cannot figure out how to implement moving up and down multiple lines like you would when navigating a word document on a normal computer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you programmed all that, and it sounds like some really nice work, so not sure if you had this idea or if it is even possible, but:
Couldn't you make the cursor move to the right x-Times when trying to go down a line, where x is the amount of characters in one line, or rather the length of the String in a line?
Depending on the way you programmed it, if there is a string for each line, you could see where the cursor is in the line you are going from (e.g at the 3rd character of the String) and then just put it there in the next line.

Comment: Hi yeah its a nice project to be working on and i thought of that but then we the problem of multiple screen sizes and some screens may have more characters per line than others. If I cant find a more elegant solution this will be the option i take